# Vague "daherkommen"

Tags: meaning, verb

> **This question also has an answer here (in German):**
>   *[Bedeutung von "daherkommen"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/38321/bedeutung-von-daherkommen)*

Why the meaning of the intransitive verb "daherkommen" is quite equivocal (I suppose)?

> 1. Der Glaube an Gott, Familie und deutsche Einheit kommt meist polemisch daher, gegen den politischen Gegner gewendet.
> 2. Die andere Option kommt etwas bescheidener daher.
> 3. Kein anderer Van der Kompaktklasse kommt derzeit so dynamisch und schwungvoll daher.
> 4. Wenn der Mensch nur noch als Homo oeconomicus daherkommt und nur noch Nutzen und Präferenzen im Kopf hat, dann wird er zum rationalen Trottel.
> 5. Der Economist nennt sich eine Zeitung, obgleich er doch als Magazin daherkommt.
> 6. Doch was auf den ersten Blick wie eine großzügige Geste des Konzerns daherkommt, entpuppt sich auf den zweiten als ein überaus fragwürdiger Handel mit der Politik.

Answer (score 4):

Why do you think they are equivocal?

The adverb "daher" can be used as an adverb of location, meaning<sup>1</sup>

1. a movement from one place to another
2. a movement without relation to a predefined location
3. a statement with relation to a cause, a fundament of knowledge.

All your examples fit in the 2nd category.

---

<sup>1: See "Grammatisch-kritisches Wörterbuch der Hochdeutschen Mundart" (1811), column 1370.</sup>

Comment: Actually, all the OP's examples fit in the 3rd category (although I'm not so sure about 'relation to a cause'). There is no movement involved whatsoever.

Comment: @Martin "kommen" is a movement for me. And with the 3rd category I meant "daher" in sense of "deswegen".

Comment: Usually yes, but its not used in that sense here. Here, it means something like "appears to be".

Comment: @Martin I do not think it plays a role, whether the movement is physical or not.

Answer (score 1):

"Daherkommen" in a non-metaphorical sense means "to come along".

In metaphorical usage this meaning is extended from persons to things and concepts.