# Bedeutung von "daherkommen"

Tags: meaning

Im Duden steht: "sich aufführen, auftreten, sich benehmen, sich betragen, sich gebärden, sich geben, sich präsentieren, sich zeigen"
Da aber "daherkommen" sich nicht ausschließlich auf Menschen bezieht, sondern auch auf Gegenstände usw., lässt sich das Verb dadurch nicht erklären.
Die Erklärung mit "sein" ist dagegen m.E. zu grob und passt meistens nicht. Könnte jemand also eine präzisere Definiton des Verben geben?
Beispiel:

> Ihm wurde vorgeworfen,dass seine Texte gestelzt daherkommen.

Comment: Ein Beispielsatzt, in dem sich ‚daherkommen‘ auf einen Gegenstand bezieht, wäre hilfreich.

Comment: Kann es sein, dass du _daherkommen_ mit _daher kommen_ verwechselst? Ich kann mir nämlich kein Beispiel erdenken, bei dem ein gegenständliches _etwas daherkommt_, wohl aber, dass _etwas daher kommt, dass ..._

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Die Wendung "etwas kommt [in irgend eine Form] daher", wie etwa in deinem Beispiel

> Ihm wurde vorgeworfen, dass seine Texte gestelzt daherkommen

mit der Grundbedeutung **"erscheinen als"** ist verbreitet in Künstler-, Dichter- und Journalistenkreisen (vielleicht auch in anderen, aber von diesen weiß ich's aus eigener Anschauung) im lockeren oder auch schnoddrigen Gespräch. Schreiben würde man es nicht, aber mit einem Glas Weißwein in der Hand nach der Dichterlesung oder Vernissage wird einem so etwas schnell mal aus dem Mund fahren.

Der Ausdruck trägt eine gewisse **Abwertung oder Kritik** mit sich. Man würde ihn nicht in lobenden Äußerungen verwenden.

Hier wären weitere Beispiele, die einem im Alltag begegnen könnten:

> Der neue Opel Fanta kommt ein bisschen altmodisch daher.
>
> Die Nachrichtensendung "Cooles Neues von Planet Blau" kommt ein bisschen zu jugendlich daher.
>
> Trumps neuer Kommunikations-Chef kam unorthodox daher.
>
> Das Theaterstück kam sehr modernistisch daher.

Ohne negative oder positive Wertung wäre dagegen der Ausdruck "[irgendwie] **rüberkommen**": Hier hängt es von den sonstigen Elementen im Satz ab, ob eine negative oder positive Wertung mitschwingt.

> Der neue Opel Mantra kommt recht schick rüber.
>
> Trumps neuer Pressesprecher kommt ausnahmsweise mal ganz normal rüber.
>
> Diese Fassung von Beethovens Neunter kommt mir zu lässig rüber.
>
> Die niedersächsische Landesregierung kommt grade ein bischen chaotisch rüber.

Comment: Ja gut, man kann Dinge natürlich vermenschlichen; aber wenn man das tut, dann kann man jedes Verb, das eigentlich nur beim Menschen angewendet wird, benutzen. Insofern wäre _daherkommen_ nur ein Beispiel.

Comment: Ich habe die Wendung nicht erfunden. Ich berichte nur aus der real existierenden Sprachpraxis.

Comment: Das weiß ich doch. Das war auch keine Kritik an deiner Antwort, sondern an die Frage des Fragestellers. Die Frage misst dem Verb _daherkommen_ eine Sonderrolle bei, die es gar nicht hat. Es wurde auf ein vermenschlichtes Ding angewendet, was man aber mit jedem anderen Verb auch machen kann.

Comment: Ach so. Ja. Richtig. Da stimme ich vollkommen zu. Es ist wirklich nur ein Beispiel von vielen für Fälle, wo Wörter, die in der Grundbedeutung eine menschliche o.ä. Tätigkeit angeben, auch auf andere Subjekte (hier: Dinge, oder auch Abstrakta) angewendet werden.

Answer (score 2):

daherkommen
(umgangssprachlich)

---

*als*

jemand zeigt sich als etwas in einer bestimmten Weise; etwas tritt als etwas, was mit einem gewissen Image verbunden ist, in Erscheinung:

jeder Film soll als Event daherkommen; dass gravierende Änderungen im Passwesen als Gesetz und nicht nur als Verordnung daherkommen, ist sinnvoll (welt.de, 30.10.2001; Google); der erste Schlaggegen Afghanistan werde weniger als eine spektakuläre, großangelegte Militäroperation daherkommen, sondern eher als eine gezielte, auf Präzision angelegte Aktion; er wollte nicht einen Film drehen, in dem die Kinder als die Besseren und die Weiseren daherkommen; Edukation und Information sollen als Entertainment daherkommen und das Lernen zum Vergnügen machen (welt.de, 2.9.2001; Google); für den Absatz von Lebensmitteln ist es ein großer Unterschied, ob die Produkte als „noname-Artikel” oder als bekannte Marke daherkommen; in Fernsehserien werden viele Klischees bedient: Schwule kommen beispielsweise häufig als exotische Paradiesvögel daher (s. grin.com, Schwule im Fernsehen; Google); Wenn ich als Fummeltante daherkomme, zwinge ich die Leute, sich mit mir und meinem „So-Sein“ auseinanderzusetzen ... (MM, Beilage Morgen Magazin vom 31. Juli bis 6. August 2003, 3).

*in*

jemand/ etwas präsentiert sich in einer bestimmten Weise, trägt etwas in irgendeiner Weise Auffallendes zur Schau:

im alten Stil daherkommen; Kultmarken wie die Zigarette F6 kommt heute noch immer in DDR-Aufmachung daher; Dateianhänge werden von ihr dann gelesen, wenn sie in einem sinnvollen Format daherkommen; wenn Priester und Ordensleute in ihren Kitteln daherkommen, das soll schön sein?; finanzielle Einschnitte, die so gerne im freundlichen Gewand von „Reformen“ daherkommen; Nietzsche lässt seine Philosophie im dichterischen Gewand daherkommen (s. amazon.de, Produktbeschreibung; Google).

*mit*

jemand/etwas kommt mit einem gewissen Anspruch, mit etwas, was ihn/es charakterisiert, mit dem er/es auftritt:

mit rhetorischem Geschick, mit flotten Sprüchen daherkommen; nicht mit einer Moralmesslatte daherkommen; wir lassen uns nicht unterstellen, dass wir mit bloßen Pastorenweisheiten daherkommen; sie gibt kluge Ratschläge, die ohne Pathos und mit Weisheit daherkommen.

*wie*

jemand erscheint wie jemand Bestimmtes:

Weltstars, die wie Seifenopern-Hanseln daherkommen; obwohl diese Frauen wie ausgepowerte Marathonläuferinnen daherkommen, strahlen sie Kraft aus (welt.de, 12.2.2000; Google).